# Vue variables are not rendering the conditional element v-if

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Problem is in two things.
1. Upon updating a variable, watch condition is not triggered.
2. element with v-if is not being shown.

```
Vue.component('comp1',{
  data: () => ({
    goClicked:false,
    showResult:false,
  }),
watch: {
    goClicked(val,v){
        console.log("goClicked changed...");
        console.log(this.goClicked+"\t"+this.showResult);
    },
    showResult(val,v){
        console.log("showResult changed...");
        console.log(this.goClicked+"\t"+this.showResult);
    }
},
methods:{
  resetValues(){
    this.goClicked=true;
    this.showResult=false;
    //DO SOMETHING
      this.showResult=true;
    this.goClicked=false;
  }
},

template:`
<v-app id="inspire">
      <p style="font-size:36px;">Testing Application.....</p>
      <v-icon @click="resetValues">create</v-icon>
      <div v-if="(!goClicked && !showResult)"><p>Initial....</p></div>
        <div v-if="goClicked"><p>Loading Page... Please wait...</p></div>
            <div v-if="showResult"><p>Result.... successs...</p></div>

  </v-app>
`
})
```

I expect the message "Loading Page... Please wait..." to be shown while debugging. But this is not happening.

Here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/satishvarada/pen/QXOLVz

Comment: if it happens in the same frame you will not see a difference. you can try this `setTimeout(() => {
   this.showResult=true;
    this.goClicked=false;
    }, 2000)` and you'll see that the watch is working just fine

Comment: Yup @AlonYampolski right. Just use this code `//DO SOMETHING
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.showResult=true;
    this.goClicked=false;
    })`